# Test presence of association breaking because of methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with one steering wheel and a related steering_wheel_color method:

```
class Car

  has_one :steering_wheel

  validates :steering_wheel, presence: true

  def steering_wheel_color
    self.steering_wheel.color
  end

end
```

When I test this model to ensure the steering wheel is present, it fails because the steering_wheel_color method becomes undefined:

```
describe "Car" do

  @car = Car.new(blah blah)

  describe "when the steering wheel is not present"
    before { @car.steering_wheel_id = "" }
    it "won't be valid" do
      @car.valid?.must_equal false
    end
  end
```

Results in something like:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `color=' for #<SteeringWheel:0x000001092f9388>
```

How can I test the presence of an association (not just the presence of a foreign key) without my test breaking because of a method?

Comment: I don't think your problem is where you think it is. Do you have `color` column on your `StearingWheel` model? If you added it recently, are you sure you migrated your test db (assuming you're using older rails version)

Comment: I'm running rails 4.1 and yes color is a column on steering_wheel. For some reason validating the presence of steering_wheel verifies any car methods that reference that object. Not quite sure why.

Comment: Try running `RAILS_ENV=test rails c` and then try `SteeringWheel.new.color='yellow'`

Comment: Did that and it works as expected. I think the problem might be elsewhere like you said.

Comment: Check the stacktrace, it should tell you what is wrong.